# Pytorch - (Categorical) Cross Entropy Loss using one hot encoding and softmax

Tags: python, pytorch, one-hot-encoding, cross-entropy

I'm looking for a cross entropy loss function in Pytorch that is like the `CategoricalCrossEntropyLoss` in Tensorflow.

My labels are one hot encoded and the predictions are the outputs of a softmax layer. For example (every sample belongs to one class):

```
targets = [0, 0, 1]
predictions = [0.1, 0.2, 0.7]
```

I want to compute the (categorical) cross entropy on the softmax values and do **not** take the max values of the predictions as a label and then calculate the cross entropy. Unfortunately, I did not find an appropriate solution since Pytorch's *CrossEntropyLoss* is not what I want and its *BCELoss* is also not exactly what I need (isn't it?).

Does anyone know which loss function to use in Pytorch or how to deal with it?
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

I thought Tensorflow's `CategoricalCrossEntropyLoss` was equivalent to PyTorch's `CrossEntropyLoss` but it seems not. The former takes OHEs while the latter takes labels as well. It seems, however, that the difference is:

- `torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss` is  a combination of `torch.nn.LogSoftmax` and `torch.nn.NLLLoss()`:

  [image]
- `tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossEntropyLoss` is something like:

  [image]

Your predictions have already been through a *softmax*. So only the negative log-likelihood needs to be applied. Based on what was discussed [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/categorical-cross-entropy-loss-function-equivalent-in-pytorch/85165/3), you could try this:

```
class CategoricalCrossEntropyLoss(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def forward(self, y_hat, y):
        return F.nll_loss(y_hat.log(), y.argmax(dim=1))
```

Above the prediction vector is converted from one-hot-encoding to label with `torch.Tensor.argmax`.

---

If that's correct why not just use `torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss` in the first place? You would just have to remove the softmax on your model's last layer and convert your targets labels.